# "sudo apt-get update" gives "0% [waiting for headers]

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, raspbian-jessie, rpi-update

As the title indicated, that is my problem.
Currently running an Rpi3 with Jessie, tried Stretch and the same problem occured.

when `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`, I have:

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free r$
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
```

Tried different mirrors, same problem.

When I ping `mirrordirector`, no problem. I can even go surfing the web on Chromium. Behaviour is similar for when I connect via Ethernet and WLAN.

I searched online and tried almost all solutions on this problem. I even enabled root (I know i'm not supposed to, I'll disable after I solve this problem).

Well when I `sudo apt-get update`, this is what I got.

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# sudo apt-get update
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie InRelease 
Ign http://archive.raspbian.org jessie InRelease                    
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie InRelease         
Err http://archive.raspbian.org jessie Release.gpg                    
 Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.191 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie Release.gpg            
  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie Release.gpg                         
  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.135.188 80]
Ign http://archive.raspbian.org jessie Release                                 
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie Release                
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie Release                             
Err http://archive.raspbian.org jessie/main Sources                            
  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.191 80]
Err http://archive.raspbian.org jessie/contrib Sources                         
  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.191 80]
Err http://archive.raspbian.org jessie/non-free Sources                        
  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.191 80]
Err http://archive.raspbian.org jessie/rpi Sources                             
  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.191 80]
Err http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main Sources                         
  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.130.104 80]
Err http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui Sources                           
  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.133 80]
Err http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main armhf Packages                  
  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.135.188 80]
Err http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui armhf Packages                    
  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.130.39 80]
Err http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main Translation-en_SG               
  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.130.104 80]
Err http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main Translation-en                  
  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.133 80]
Err http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui Translation-en_SG                 
  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.135.188 80]
Err http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui Translation-en                    
  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.130.39 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main armhf Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib armhf Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free armhf Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi armhf Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib Translation-en_SG
  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib Translation-en
  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main Translation-en_SG
  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main Translation-en
  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en_SG
  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en
  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi Translation-en_SG
  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi Translation-en
  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/Release.gpg  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/Release.gpg  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.191 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/jessie/Release.gpg  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.135.188 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/main/source/Sources  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.191 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/contrib/source/Sources  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.191 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/non-free/source/Sources  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.191 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/rpi/source/Sources  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.191 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/main/binary-armhf/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/contrib/binary-armhf/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/non-free/binary-armhf/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/rpi/binary-armhf/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/contrib/i18n/Translation-en_SG  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/contrib/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/main/i18n/Translation-en_SG  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/main/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/non-free/i18n/Translation-en_SG  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/non-free/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/rpi/i18n/Translation-en_SG  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/rpi/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/source/Sources  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.130.104 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/jessie/ui/source/Sources  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.133 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/binary-armhf/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.135.188 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/jessie/ui/binary-armhf/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.130.39 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/i18n/Translation-en_SG  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.130.104 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.133 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/jessie/ui/i18n/Translation-en_SG  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.135.188 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/jessie/ui/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed [IP: 93.93.130.39 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Can't be a lack of memory problem, I have a 32Gb Class 10 memory card installed. Sorry for wasting anyone's time but I did some extensive searching and still can't find a solution.

Help :(

Comment: Is there a reason why you haven't re-flashed your sd card with the latest Raspbain Stretch?

Comment: My first attempt was with Stretch but my friend here said his problem was solved when he flashed Jessie.

Comment: Please try first a simple `ping` to any of the IP addresses mentioned. This looks like a network problem you have.

Comment: possibly behind a firewall that requires sign in?

Comment: Tried two different source of ISP, still no problem. @ChadG

Comment: Yes. I tried to ping the ip address and got 100% packet loss. Any idea to resolve? @UwePlonus

Comment: Tried `ping 93.93.128.193` and no problem but ping `93.93.128.193 80` returns with packet loss. Ping does not travel on port 80. Ping to the ip address alone comes out fine. @UwePlonus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem Solved**

Tried a third source of internet and finally went through. Looks like my ISP blocked the connection.

Comment: Can you please give us the solution? or give us the link you have used to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I've had also the [waiting for headers] problem, but didn't get the "connection failed" message.

Instead, I've could check that was getting a timeout for the headers. I checked this using `sudo strace apt-get update`.

The solution was to increase the timeout at `/etc/apt/apt.conf` (create it if you don't have it):

`Acquire::http::Timeout "30";`

Then the update worked. This solution was mainly adapted from the answers to this [question](https://serverfault.com/q/106033).

**PS**.: I was behind a corporate firewall and vlan.